# highcharts highstock xrange large data

Tags: highcharts, xrange

I try display with Highcharts-Xrange 70,000 measuring points. However, after a few hundred no longer a graph is drawn

I work with C #, Ajax, Java

The project itself is unfortunately several hundred Mb big, I put a small data extract the Data file in.

```
     var ChartData = [{"pointWidth":5,"data":[
        {"x":1460655420413,"x2":1460655422865,"y":10,"EName":"OVR 1","EValue":" / Wert: 90 %","color":""},
        {"x":1460655452292,"x2":1460655454414,"y":10,"EName":"OVR 1","EValue":" / Wert: 2 %","color":""},
        {"x":1460655456383,"x2":1460655457342,"y":10,"EName":"OVR 1","EValue":" / Wert: 4 %","color":""},
        {"x":1460655457342,"x2":1460655488705,"y":10,"EName":"OVR 1","EValue":" / Wert: 100 %","color":""},
        {"x":1460655490963,"x2":1460655495353,"y":10,"EName":"OVR 1","EValue":" / Wert: 70 %","color":""},
        {"x":1460655495353,"x2":1460655497142,"y":10,"EName":"OVR 1","EValue":" / Wert: 6 %","color":""},   
        ...
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the threshold parameter as 0 ? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.threshold

Comment: Hi, yes i tried.

I get allways this exeption:
TypeError: can't convert undefined to object
error source line:
 
error source line:
 

...[b].stopped=!0};n=function(a,b){return Array.prototype.forEach.call(a,b)};D=func...

 
@ highstock.js (Zeile 26, Spalte 271)
...[b].stopped=!0};n=function(a,b){return Array.prototype.forEach.call(a,b)};D=func...
--^

Comment: Are you able to replicate this issue in native JS (without c# / Java) with hardcoded data?

Comment: i create this small sample with 10000 Datapoints

http://jsfiddle.net/b0e6b2sf/

Comment: i found an error, i must use threshold and turbothreshold than it works in that example.

Comment: But now is the next error there:
TypeError: l[g] is undefined

and the tooltips aren´t working anymore :(

Comment: For me it works: http://jsfiddle.net/gyun8q3a/, can you update the example to introduce the first error ?